# Vertical Text Alignment

Tags: css

I have a vertical page label with various lengths, i.e. news, awards, publications. I would like the text to start at the same top point (if the text was horizontal it would be justified right) and go down from that point. I am having to use an inline style to push the text down to be n the correct location. I tried setting height and width to 500, which seems to work for alignment but pushes the div to the right way over.

```
.vert_text {
position: relative;
color: #fff;
text-transform: lowercase;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 6em;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
float:left;
width:100px;
}

<div class="vert_text">
news
</div>
<div class="vert_text">
publications
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height and define a height for example :

```
.vert_text {
    height:6em;
    line-height:6em;
}
```

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/gdArF/1/).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to make some space between each vertical text ?

Comment: no i need the vertical text's last letter to be in the same location without doing an inline style. Please see the news, awards and publications links here  http://lightingdesignalliance.com/news/index-jas/

Comment: Ok you want them to be at the same position on each page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.var_text{
margin-top:0px;
}
```

or

> delete position:relative

then add

> margin:0px or margin-top:0px;

Comment: I created a Fiddle for this can you show what you mean here? http://jsfiddle.net/Qv2rs/